# how to make a grid mobile responsive in react

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have to make videos in the grid to appear horizontally one after the other when seen in a mobile(mobile responsive) but they should stay vertically aligned in desktop view.

i have tried giving values to rows and columns as auto

```
    return (
          <div>
            <h1 className="text">trending in youtube</h1>

            <div className="grid-container">
              <div className="one">
                <YouTube
                  videoId="y6fThXQPT6I"
                  opts={opts}
                  onReady={this._onReady}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="two">
                <YouTube
                  videoId="bo_efYhYU2A"
                  opts={opts}
                  onReady={this._onReady}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="three">
                <YouTube
                  videoId="3AtDnEC4zak"
                  opts={opts}
                  onReady={this._onReady}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
```

css file

```
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto, 1fr);
      grid-gap: 5px;
      grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    }

    .text {
      margin-top: 50px;
      margin-left: 40%;
    }
    .one {
      grid-column: auto;
      grid-row: 1;
    }
    .two {
      grid-column:auto;
      grid-row: 1;
    }
    .three {
      grid-column: auto;
      grid-row: 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you tagged your post with `bootstrap-4` I'll assume you use it.

Bootstrap has all you need, look at the grid system: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/

In your case you can use it like this:

```
return (
  <div className="container">
    <h1 className="text">trending in youtube</h1>

    <div className="row justify-content-center">
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <YouTube
          videoId="y6fThXQPT6I"
          opts={opts}
          onReady={this._onReady}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <YouTube
          videoId="bo_efYhYU2A"
          opts={opts}
          onReady={this._onReady}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
        <YouTube
          videoId="3AtDnEC4zak"
          opts={opts}
          onReady={this._onReady}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

No more CSS needed

Comment: No need to import full library to achieve it while it could be done in 1 css property

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `grid-auto-flow`:

```
   .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 5px;
      grid-auto-flow: row; /* appear Vertically*/
      justify-items: center;
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) { 
      .grid-container { 
        grid-auto-flow: column; /* appear Horizontally on mobile phones*/
      }
    }
```

Example About css `grid-auto-flow` property: When you run the snippet it will appear horizontally, but if you opened it as full screen it will appear vertically.

```css
   .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-gap: 5px;
      grid-auto-flow: row;
      justify-items: center;
    }
    @media (max-width: 767px) { 
      .grid-container { 
        grid-auto-flow: column;
      }
    }
    .item {
      width: 250px;
      height: 100px;
    }

    .one {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }

    .two {
      background-color: lightpink;
    }

    .three {
      background-color: lightcoral;
    }
```

```html
  <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item one"></div>
      <div class="item two"></div>
      <div class="item three"></div>
    </div>
```